# Transformer with 5 secondary taps, is the connections correct?

Tags: transformer, voltage-regulator, bridge-rectifier

I have a transformer with five taps on the secondary, one wire (black) is the common to four wires:

| blue | green | black | green | blue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 15 | 0 | 15 | 30 |

Is the diagram below correct?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffxfCZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Are you sure the blacks are connected internally?

Comment: @Transistor There's only one black and the voltage readings are in the question.

Comment: It is very unusual to have a centre-tap shared between two windings with the same voltages. 30 - 15 - 0 - 15 - 30 or similar would be common but not 15 - 15 - 0 - 15 - 15.

Comment: Look what happens with the top tap goes negative. The two diodes from '-' to '~' in BR1 are forward biased and short the top tap to GND. A very large current will flow and probably blow two of the diodes in BR1.

Comment: did you measure the resistance between the five wires?

Comment: @Transistor one of them outputting 30-0-30, but I changed it to 15-0-15 because I knew someone will show up saying that you exceeded the 7805 maximum input voltage... the voltage regulators are there just to demonstrate the situation.

Comment: @jsotola Right, I will edit the transformer symbol.

Comment: We can't help you if you give us misleading information.

Comment: @Transistor I'm sorry, I was just trying to make things simpler, editing the question now.

Comment: Right. Well then just replace them with resistors to show the load connection.

Comment: @Transistor Done.

Comment: @jsotola Does it look any better now?

Comment: swap the bottom connection of BR1 and the bottom connection of BR2

Comment: @jsotola Is it correct now?

Comment: Closer. BR1 is fed from a '+'30 V tap and a '-'15 V tap. BR2 is fed from a '+'15 V tap and a '-'30 V tap. BR1 still shorts when either ~ input goes negative. Disconnect the negative lead on BR1 and just use half of the bridge.

Comment: @Transistor How about now? "A very large current will flow and probably blow two of the diodes in BR1" How can I avoid that? I need a 30V and a +-15V from this supply. edit: oh sorry didn't see your edit to your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWoZeF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Disconnect the red wires.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f57mWs.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. The equivalent circuit.*

The rectified 30 V supply load current will return to the XFMR1's centre-tap.